# Dynamically build simply-typed java objects from JSON REST

Tags: java, android, json, jackson, retrofit

I am consuming a REST API using Retrofit. I can receive the JSON object and print it. I want to dynamically convert it to a nested simply typed Java object.

i.e. I want the Java object to consist of nested Map, Array, String, Int/Double, Boolean, and null built dynamically based on the JSON object (similar to json.loads in Python). I'm attempting to use Jackson for this. Here's what I have:

```
API api = APIHandler.getApiInterface();
api.getFoo(new Callback<Object>() {
    @Override
    public void success(Object o, Response response) {
        Log.i("Tag", "Print JSON " + o.toString());

        ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
        Map<String, Object> json = mapper.readValue(o, Map.class);

    }

    @Override
    public void failure(RetrofitError error) {

    }
});
```

The JSON is logged but the line `mapper.readValue(o, Map.class);` gives a "cannot resolve method" error. Changing the return type to String seems to cause more problems.

What's the right way to do this?

Comment: Why are you using jackson when android have a core API to do that? Take a look to http://developer.android.com/reference/org/json/JSONObject.html#JSONObject(java.lang.String)

Comment: Here you have some comparison: http://java.dzone.com/articles/be-lazy-productive-android

Comment: Thanks for the tips. JSONObject is close to what I was looking for but seems clunky. I'm starting to think that in Java, I should really be converting the JSON to POJOs, no?

Answer (score 0):

Insted `Object o` your shoud use custom class. So use `new Callback<MyMapper>` instead new `Callback<Object>`.

e.g.

```
public class MyMapper {
    public String name; 
    public int age; 
}
```